# searching in a pandas df that contains ranges

Tags: python, pandas, numeric-ranges

I have a pandas df that contains 2 columns 'start' and 'end' (both are integers). I would like an efficient method to search for rows such that the range that is represented by the row [start,end] contains a specific value.

Two additional notes:

1. It is possible to assume that ranges don't overlap
2. The solution should support a batch mode - that given a list of inputs, the output will be a mapping (dictionary or whatever) to the row indices that contain the matching range.

For example:

```
       start   end
0      7216    7342
1      7343    7343
2      7344    7471
3      7472    8239
4      8240    8495
```

and the query of

```
[7215,7217,7344]
```

will result in

```
{7217: 0, 7344: 2}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show an example of your input and desired output?

Comment: Please provide a sample input and desired ouput data.

Comment: Thanks, I have update my question to include inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force solution, could use lots of improvements though.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': [7216, 7343, 7344, 7472, 8240],
                   'end': [7342, 7343, 7471, 8239, 8495]})

search = [7215, 7217, 7344]
res = {}
for i in search:
    mask = (df.start <= i) & (df.end >= i)
    idx = df[mask].index.values
    if len(idx):
        res[i] = idx[0]
print res
```

Yields

```
{7344: 2, 7217: 0}
```

Comment: Simple and efficient ! I've played with this question to find a solution, but it was not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

### Selected solution

This new solution could have better performances. But there is a limitation, it will only works if there is no gap between ranges like in the example provided.

```
# Test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': [7216, 7343, 7344, 7472, 8240], 
                   'end': [7342, 7343, 7471, 8239, 8495]}, columns=['start','end'])

query = [7215,7217,7344]

# Reshaping the original DataFrame
df = df.reset_index()
df = pd.concat([df['start'], df['end']]).reset_index()
df = df.set_index(0).sort_index()
# Creating a DataFrame with a continuous index
max_range = max(df.index) + 1
min_range = min(df.index)
s = pd.DataFrame(index=range(min_range,max_range))
# Joining them
s = s.join(df)
# Filling the gaps
s = s.fillna(method='backfill')
# Then a simple selection gives the result
s.loc[query,:].dropna().to_dict()['index']

# Result
{7217: 0.0, 7344: 2.0}
```

### Previous proposal

```
# Test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': [7216, 7343, 7344, 7472, 8240], 
                   'end': [7342, 7343, 7471, 8239, 8495]}, columns=['start','end'])

# Constructing a DataFrame containing the query numbers
query = [7215,7217,7344]
result = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(query, (len(df), 1)), columns=query)

# Merging the data and the query
df = pd.concat([df, result], axis=1)

# Making the test
df = df.apply(lambda x: (x >= x['start']) & (x <= x['end']), axis=1).loc[:,query]
# Keeping only values found
df = df[df==True]
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=(0,1))
# Extracting to the output format
result = df.to_dict('split')
result = dict(zip(result['columns'], result['index']))

# The result
{7217: 0, 7344: 2}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this is similar to something I have already tried, but my main concern is memory: the real df has about 40 million rows and my query has about 12K entires. In my previous solution I split the query but it was very slow. Is there a way to avoid the split?

Comment: Just provided a new solution, tell me if it can be used with your data volume.

Comment: I just figured that there is a bug in my answer. I will work on it later but I thing the idea is interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This solution is better - but since the ranges are quite large and this may cause the s dataframe to become too large, in my final solution I'm splitting the query and only take the subset of rows from the ranges dataframe that are relevant. This makes the row expansion of s in the proposed solution work well. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to hear my answer helped. It was not obvious. In consequence, I've modifed the description to indicate the chosen solution.